# Flutter remote redirect URI for mobile app user authentication with keycloak backend

Tags: flutter, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a minikube cluster running a set of microservices, with one of them hosting a [keycloak deployment via a helm chart](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak), and Im looking to create a flutter mobile client application to authenticate against it

I see that flutter has auth plugins such as the [Flutter AppAuth plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth) and such, but most of the docs I read prescribe specifying the OIDC `redirect_uri` parameter to something along the lines of `com.app.name://login-callback`. However, Im hoping to have a "remote" redirect URI such as `http://my.app.name/api/auth/callback` which **in addition to fetching the auth token** also performs some domain specific operations

For example, if a user were to login with Google SSO against the keycloak client, then I want the user to be created within my application domain after successfully retrieving the `access_token` so that there isn't a dangling user that is available within keycloak but not anywhere else

This is not a problem for web clients because hitting the login endpoint `api/auth/login` will redirect to SSO provider and then redirect back to `http://my.app.name/api/auth/callback` which will take care of

1. Trading auth code for auth token
2. Creating new user in system if it does not exist
3. Updating custom token claims for future use

How can I follow the same approach on the mobile app for authentication? As far as I see, mobile app OIDC auth employs the use of "virtual redirect URIs" along the lines of `com.app.name://login-callback` which will not allow me to perform the extra operations I hope to do.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed some light on this or prescribe any best practices to tackle the scenario in which a new app user uses SSO login/create-account for the **first time**

Answer (score 1):

You can try [deep linking](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking) on flutter. Then open the browser with `externalApplication` mode using [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) which opens the browser in external mode. Then it will open your app after the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Deep links are URIs of any scheme that takes users directly to a specific part of your app. It is very useful for working with OIDC because your app wants to redirect_uri to redirect your application from the web browser or web view. So we can use deep links in flutter [deep linking in flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking).

If you want to create a callback URL, Add this code `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity" 
            android:exported="true">                                                    
        <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="com.example.andidoor" android:host="example.host"/>
       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now, this is a callback Url format (deep link format) `com.app.name://login-callback` and now you can add `scheme://host` like `com.example.andidoor://example.host`